# Javascript regex match only inside parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an data.url string. I want to get some data from it with the following regex

```
    var filename = data.url.match(/file=(.+)&/gi);
```

All I want is the data inside the parenthesis -a file name actually- but what I get back is "file=example.jpg&".
Why is this happening? Shouldn't only the the matches found in the parentheses be returned?
How can I get rid of those unnecessary characters? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var filename = data.url.match(/file=([^&]+)/i)[1];
```

Example:

```
"file=example.jpg".match(/file=([^&]+)/i)[1] == "example.jpg"
"file=example.jpg&b=ttt&c=42".match(/file=([^&]+)/i)[1] == "example.jpg"
"http://example.com/index.php?file=example.jpg&b=ttt&c=42".match(/file=([^&]+)/i)[1] == "example.jpg"
```

`match()` returns an array with the first searched group at the second place, i.e. at `match(...)[1]`.

**Note:** The result of the above code will be a String. If you still want to have a singleton array with your filename as the only element, then you should take the solution of @Sabuj Hassan.

Comment: Hmm, if you're using `[^&]+`, then you can safely remove the `&?` at the end. Unless OP specifically wants to match if there's a `&`, in which case, you shouldn't use the `?`.

Comment: @Jerry: Thanks! I will rewrite my solution to the shorter regex... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`Javascript` returns both the whole matched pattern(usually known as group-0) along with the other matched groups. You can use this one:

```
var filename = /file=(.+)&/gi.exec(data.url).slice(1);
```