# Using lookarounds to find a match javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to extract a ID from a text using regex. For example **05771292000P** from:

```
<div class="product-price-container">     <a href="/rca-32-class-720p-60hz-led-hdtv-with-built-in-dvd-player-led32b30rqd/226660215" class="product-link subject-price" data-external-product-id="05771292000P">    <span class="save-story-box">
```

Tried using the regex `(?=id=").*">`but it returns ever word after id, which is not helpful.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not considering using a proper parser? `(?= ... )` is lookahead, and you're using it like a lookbehind here (lookbehinds are not supported by javascript). You would be slightly better off with `id="([^"]*)"`.

Comment: id="([^"]*)" returns id="05771292000P". 
I need only 05771292000P, this is why I tried using lookarounds.

Comment: Well, look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22870673/1578604) then.

Comment: [**I'd much rather look at one of the most upvoted questions on SO**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var text = '<div class="product-price-container">     <a href="/rca-32-class-720p-60hz-led-hdtv-with-built-in-dvd-player-led32b30rqd/226660215" class="product-link subject-price" data-external-product-id="05771292000P">    <span class="save-story-box">'
text.match(/data-external-product-id="([0-9A-Za-z]+)"/)[1]
```

`match(...)` returns an array with the whole match as the first element and your group match (i.e. `[0-9A-Za-z]+`) as the second element. If you can trust the source from where you get the text, you can also use jQuery ([here the code on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TCErg/)):

```
var text = '<div class="product-price-container">     <a href="/rca-32-class-720p-60hz-led-hdtv-with-built-in-dvd-player-led32b30rqd/226660215" class="product-link subject-price" data-external-product-id="05771292000P">    <span class="save-story-box">'

var id = $($.parseHTML(text)).find("a").attr("data-external-product-id")

alert(id) // 05771292000P
```

Please have in mind, that everyone can execute malicious JavaScript with `$.parseHTML` if he has control over the parsed text. So only use the above solution, if you have control over the parsed text.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:
id="([0-9A-Za-z]+)"

Comment: Same as the above comment. This returns id="05771292000P", and I need 05771292000P. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: the () are used to capture value. It will return you 05771292000P when you do var result = regex.exec(yourString);

here result will be an array